# Are there any "horizontal" IDEs for OOP?

Tags: python, oop, ide

This always comes to my mind when scrolling through my Python files in Sublime Text, there is is just so much "horizontal" space left, and we programmers and technology enthusiasts are always thriving for efficiency!

What I'm talking about is, organize blocks of code in chunks of the screen, like a grid. Most notably classes in the same file, equally organized across your screen, instead of just scrolling up and down all the time.

I know some languages like Java already have this sorta solved with one class per file

Comment: You could always open two editors side-by-side; that's part of the reason why many style guides have a line length limit! I'm not sure if there's a way of displaying by class, however, especially with Sublime.

Comment: [PEP-8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) "Limiting the required editor window width makes it possible to have several files open side-by-side, and works well when using code review tools that present the two versions in adjacent columns."

Comment: Thanks, found what I was looking for, View>Layout>Grid in Sublime text and Sync View Scroll package